# How to use beautifulsoup to get redirect html?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at a web file with the following header. How could I get the content of google.com page with bs4?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://google.com"/>  
</head>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`  with tag name `meta`, and `attrs` having the known fixed attribute, namely `http-equiv` needs to have value of `refresh`. Get the first such element from the result set, and take the value of its `'content'` attribute, then parse it for url.

Thus you get:

```
>>> fragment = """<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://google.com"/></head>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(fragment)
>>> element = soup.find('meta', attrs={'http-equiv': 'refresh'})
>>> element
<meta content="5;url=http://google.com" http-equiv="refresh"/>

>>> refresh_content = element['content']
>>> refresh_content
u'5;url=http://google.com'

>>> url = refresh_content.partition('=')[2]
>>> url
u'http://google.com'
```

Comment: does findChildren serve the same functioanlity as findall?

Comment: Ah, better to just use `find` here as we are only interested in 1.